# What css is causing my odd word wrap?

Tags: css, browser, blogs, word-wrap

On [my blog](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/) its showing a very odd word wrap on browsers. I have checked the text and its fine, no hard returns. What could cause this? How can It be fixed? First photo is firefox, and the second one is chrome and safari.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your *blog* gonna be everywhere on SO :)

Comment: what do you mean @HashemQolami ?

Comment: Recently I see some posts start with *"On my blog, its ..."* on SO, And accidentally it's yours :)

Comment: oh. im trying to put the finishing touches on my site, and i need help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at your coding, and it is because of the markup. You have **multiple usages** of `&nbsp` throughout the markup. You need to remove them, they are causing your problem..

Look at the following image.

[image]